# Руставелевские или руставелиевские

Tags: орфография, словообразование

Как правильно: Руставелевские чтения, или руставелиевские? Пожалуйста, со ссылкой на источник или правило. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

***Руставелиевские.*** 
Ну какое может быть правило? В русском И - часть корня, она не должна теряться при образовании производных.
Фиксаций у слова "руставелиевский" достаточно.
http://sklonenie.gramatik.ru/rustavelievskiy

Правда, есть исключения, но Руставели к ним относиться не должен, сохранение полной основы закреплено не только общими нормами, но и традицией для конкретного имени.

> со ссылкой на источник

Ну вот такой вас устроит?

> День добрый! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как образовать прилагательное от фамилии Дали.
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Ваш вопрос интересный и сложный. В доступных нам источниках прилагательное от фамилии *Дали* не зафиксировано.
>
> Академическая «Русская грамматика» 1980 года указывает, что после гласных в
>   прилагательных, мотивированных несклоняемыми топонимами, этнонимами,
>   фамилиями, аббревиатурами, выступают морфы *-йск-*, *-нск-*, *-вск-*.
>   Здесь же зафиксировано прилагательное от *ИФЛИ - ифлийский*, от *Верди
>   - вердиевский*, от *Руставели - руставелиевский* (правда, в фамилиях *Верди* и *Руставели* ударение не падает на последний слог, а фамилии *Дали* падает). С другой стороны, есть примеры прилагательных, образованных от слов с ударным *-ли*: *филёвский* (от *Фили*),
>   *жигулёвский* (от *Жигули*). На наш взгляд, если выбирать между грамматически возможными вариантами *далийский, далиевский* и
>   *далёвский*, то предпочтительно: *далиевский*.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9

Привожу полностью, поскольку здесь обсуждает как раз вопрос о возвможном подобном усечении основы - для фамилии Дали. Я согласен со "Справкой" во всем, кроме сопоставления наших случаев с "Фили" или "Жигули" - эти два топонима склоняются (В Фил**ях**, Жигул**ях**) и, соответственно, конечное И там флексия, а не часть корня.

Так что "далиевский" - единственный принимаемый мной вариант. 
Ну и с ***руставелиевский*** сомнений быть не должно в любом случае.